# Obtaining new/old values from two seperate employee records in same table

Tags: sql, select, nested, statements

I want to print one row of data for each employee in a database table, and each employee has 2 rows of data, one for their current job positon, and the other for their backup position.

The Employee table looks like this for each employee:

```
|EMPLNO| FNAME | LNAME    |JOBNO| TITLE | TITLE_DT  |STATUS|
------------------------------------------------------------
|  577 | Jon   | Albeary  | 1   | 54737 | 8/15/2016 | C    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  577 |  Jon  | Albeary  | 2   | 8297A | 4/1/2019  | T    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The results should look like this:

```
|EMPLNO| FNAME | LNAME    |JOBNO| TITLE | TITLE_DT  |STATUS| BKUP_TITLE | BKUP_TITLE_DT  |BKUP_STATUS|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  577 | Jon   | Albeary  | 1   | 54737 | 8/15/2016 | C    | 8297A      | 4/1/2019       | T         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The SQL requirement is to look for all records with `(JOBNO = '1') AND(EMPL_CLASS <> 'A')` but have a record with `(JOBNO = '2') AND (TITLE = '54737')`.  I obtained the results, but don't know how to obtain the information from the second record to have it listed on one row.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT EMPLNO, FNAME, LNAME, STATUS, TITLE, TITLE_DT 
FROM  EMPLOYEE
WHERE (EMPLNO IN
           (SELECT EMPLNO
            FROM  EMPLOYEE AS EMPLOYEE_1
            WHERE (JOBNO = '2') AND (TITLE = '54737'))) 
AND (JOBNO = '1') AND (STATUS <> 'A');
```

However, that query only gives me the record with JOBNO = 1.  Can anyone help me write a query to print the data from both records with JOBNO = 1 and JOBNO = 2 on a single line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a join to the table itself by first selecting all the records for jobno = 2, then joining that to the records where jobno = 1 where the employee number matches.

```
    select a.emplno, a.fname, a.lname, a.status, b.title as bkup_title, b.title_dt as bkup_title_dt, b.status as bkup_Status
    from (select * from employee where jobno = '2' and title = '54737') b
    join employee a
    on a.emplno = b.emplno
    wherre a.jobno = '1' and a.status <> 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sotark.  This suggestion worked perfectly.  Well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select e.*,
  ee.title as BKUP_TITLE, ee.title_dt as BKUP_TITLE_DT, ee.status as BKUP_STATUS
from employee e inner join employee ee
on ee.emplno = e.emplno
where e.status<> 'A' and e.title = '54737' and e.jobno = 1 and ee.jobno = 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Ai2nAfzAtvYZAkNjHMNGE/2).
Results:

```
| EMPLNO | FNAME | LNAME   | JOBNO | TITLE | TITLE_DT   | STATUS | BKUP_TITLE | BKUP_TITLE_DT | BKUP_STATUS |
| ------ | ----- | ------- | ----- | ----- | ---------- | ------ | ---------- | --------------| ----------- |
| 577    | Jon   | Albeary | 1     | 54737 | 2016-08-05 | C      | 8297A      | 2019-04-01    | T           |
```

Comment: Thank you very much, forpas.  This suggestion will be useful when I am looking for a specific title. Well appreciated.